How to do CREATE for tables with foreign key in ASP.NET C#
{
   "FacilityID":"18c9aebb-0874-4fc2-900e-48f6b192797f",
   "FacilityRoomNumber":102,
   "FacilityPurpose":"DSFDSF",
   "LabTypeID":"bde03bf9-2fec-4d4c-bc00-e8fc605703a5",
   "LabType":{
      "LabTypeID":"bde03bf9-2fec-4d4c-bc00-e8fc605703a5",
      "LabTypeName":"CT Scan",
      "Facilities":[]
   },
   "LabResults":null
}

LabType field is required.
I am creating a facility which has LabTypeID as a foreign key. I can read from the table, which probably means all the FKs and tables are set correctly, but I can't add into database. Although LabType field has the values, the error says it is required.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FacilityRoomNumber,FacilityPurpose,LabTypeID")] Facility facility)
{
    facility.FacilityID = Guid.NewGuid();

    var labtype = await _context.LabTypes.FindAsync(facility.LabTypeID);

    if (labtype != null)
    {
        facility.LabType = labtype;
        _context.Entry(facility).State = EntityState.Modified; // ensure ef tracks the changes
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "the specified lab type does not exist.");
        return View(facility);
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("valid context");
        _context.Facilities.Add(facility);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("index", "facilities");
    }
    else
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(facility, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    return View(facility);
}


Try to remove the entire part that pulls the labtype from the database and sets it. It should be enough for facility to have a LabTypeID value.
